# The limit of a pointwise converging sequence of polynomial is smooth

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, pointwise-convergence

Let $(P_n)_{n\geqslant 0}$ being a sequence of real polynomials with non negative coefficients, that converge pointwise on $\mathbb{R}$ to a functoin $f$. Then:

> $f\in \mathcal{C}^{\infty}$.

How one can prove that?

Comment: This is interesting. Can you provide some more insight? There are sequences of polynomials converging pointwise to non-smooth functions; for example, $$p_n(x):=\sum_{j=0}^n \binom{\frac12}{j}(x^2-1)^j$$ converges to $|x|$ for all $x\in [-1, 1]$. This is not in contradiction with your claim, however, because here the coefficients are not all positive, and the sequence converges on an interval instead of all $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Can you show such sequences exist?   Polynomials $\to \pm \infty$ as $|x|\to \infty$.

Comment: Such sequences exist, just take a sequence like $f_n(x)=x/n$ or even the first $n$ terms of the Taylor expansion of $e^x$.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro see my comment to the accepted answer, I give some insights...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your tags don't include complex analysis, but that approach gives a quick proof, so I'll post it.

We can consider each $P_n(x)=\sum_{m=0}^{M_n}a_{mn}x^m$ as defined on all of $\mathbb C,$ simply by replacing $x\in \mathbb R$ with $z\in \mathbb C.$ Suppose $|z|\le R.$ Then

$$|P_n(z)| = |\sum_{m=0}^{M_n}a_{mn}z^m| \le  \sum_{m=0}^{M_n}| a_{mn}z^m|$$ $$\le \sum_{m=0}^{M_n}a_{mn}R^m = P_n(R).$$

But the sequence $P_n(R)$ converges, hence is bounded. This shows $|P_n(z)|$ is uniformly bounded on each disc $\{|z|\le R\}.$

By Montel's theorem, there is a subsequence $P_{n_k}$ that converges uniformly on each $\{|z|\le R\}$ to an entire function $g.$ Since $P_n \to f$ pointwise on $\mathbb R,$ the same is true of $P_{n_k}.$ It follows that $f=g$ on $\mathbb R.$ Thus $f$ is not just $C^\infty,$ but is the restriction of an entire function to the real axis.

Comment: Thank you, this is nice. To answer other comments here, I had in mind that (with your notation) that juste taking $x=1$ gives $\sum_m a_{nm}$ bounded so that thanks to positivity, each $(a_{nm})_n$ is bounded (by a constant uniform in $m$) and we can extract using a diagonal trick so that up to extracting a subsequence we have $a_{nm} \to a_m$ and then there would have some work to do. But that was the basic idea...

Comment: Very nice. The second $=$ in the big formula should be $\le$.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro  Thank you, corrected.